# how can I read xsd documentation value in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

how can I read xsd documentation value in c#?

Example:

```
    XmlSchemaAttribute awdaw = new XmlSchemaAttribute();
    XmlSchemaAnnotation annotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation();
    XmlSchemaDocumentation doc = new XmlSchemaDocumentation();

    doc.Markup = TextToNodeArray("description");
    doc.Language = "en";
    annotation.Items.Add(doc);
    awdaw.Annotation = annotation;
    readXMLdocumentation(awdaw);

    string readXMLdocumentation(XmlSchemaAttribute att)
    {
        var wada = new XmlSchemaAnnotation();
        wada = att.Annotation;
        wada.Items.??????
    }
```

but how do I get documentation value?

Comment: You are try to read or create? Your question asking about read, but your sample is create new object.

Comment: I try to read, i know how to create, but idk how to get documentation value (pls see "readXMLdocumentation")